# Unable to position content to be center in flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a `Header` component as below

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Header = () => (
  <div className={className}>
    <div>LEFT</div>
    <div className="progress-bar">CENTER</div>
    <div>RIGHT</div>
  </div>
);

const StyledHeader = styled(Header)`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
`;

export default StyledHeader;
```

And below is the content of `.progress-bar`

```css
.progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Initially **CENTER** was positioned center due to `justify-content: space-between` defined at `StyledHeader`, the problem was `background-color: green` can only take very little space, so I proceed to define a CSS style, to make it `flex: 1` in order to take as much space as possible, but I couldnt position it to be `center` anymore?

Comment: you only need text-align:center for the progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div element with class `progress-bar` should be a flex container in order for its children to be affected by properties of flexbox

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;              <--------
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see! I thought since `StyledHeader` is a `flexbox` and so all of it's nested component will be treated as `flexbox`!

Answer (score 1):

Add text-align: center; like this:

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you have other content (eg: html elements) that you want to position to the center inside `.progress-bar`, then you need to add `display: flex;`, like this:

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have not put any tag for 'CENTER' text. just put a p tag on it, then it should work.